# React - Hot Reload with Django template

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack

---

Is hot reloading possible while mounting react components into our Django template?

As part of improving our UX, we are adding react component to our page to bring dynamic content on every customer interaction.

I have successfully set up the react inside our Django and placed bundle.js into a static path using Webpack. Now using [Webpack watch](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) we are able to load the latest changes on the page.

In this setup, we can't bring hot reloading and source in the browser devtools console to debug and speed up our development.

Note: The application is not a SPA also not a Restful design for now.